# Serie de números del 1 al 100

Tags: java

```
public class Secuencia_1_al_100 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int num;
        System.out.println("Secuencia de numeros");
        System.out.println("Del 0 al 100");
        System.out.print("Serie: ");

        for (num=1;num<=100;num++)
        {
            System.out.print(num+",");
        }
    }
}
```

Hola chicos este trabajo me lo dejaron de proyecto, todo agarra a la perfección con respecto a la serie pero me piden que dentro de la serie los números que van en relación con el 5 los elimine y vaya como esta sucesión `1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 16 ...` y así sucesivamente pero no se cual es el código para poder omitir ese número.

Espero lean esto y se los agradeceré.

Comment: ¿por qué la secuencia final no incluye el número `3`? No entiendo que _relación_ tiene el `3` con el `5`. Creo que vendría bien que nos expliques que debe entenderse por una _relación_ entre los números de la secuencia y el `5`

Comment: Lo siento men si es cierto es que se me paso el 3... De todos modos gracias por la correcion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para no mostrar ningun multiplo de 5 puedes hacer uso del operador % (MOD), el cual devuelve el resto de la division entre 2 numeros, ejemplo:

```
System.out.println(10 % 2); // 0
System.out.println(10 % 3); // 1
System.out.println(10 % 5); // 0
```

para validar que el numero a imprimir no es multiplo de 5 puedes usar un condicional if :

```
   for (num=1;num<=100;num++)
{
    if(num%5!=0){ // si no es multiplo de 5, realiza la instruccion.
       System.out.print(num+",");
}
```

Comment: Hola Cristian Figueroa si me ha servido mucho tu apoyo. De verdad muchas gracias me ayudaste mucho. Ten lindo dia men.